# Specific UIImages and UIImageView help on theory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

I've been trying to figure out UIImage for some time now. I've been trying to figure out an approach to having one view the 'Main Game View' and showing either 2/3/4 different images depending on the 'level' variable. I'm just trying to be sure of logic. So for example level 1 would display 4 pictures and level 2 might display 3 different pictures. I don't want to hinder performance of the app but because the game is to be played offline and archiving won't make much of a difference all the images (several hundred optimised images) are being stored locally in the main app bundle.

I'm just wondering if my logic for trying to implement this so far is sound or not. For level 1 I would implement the 4 UIImageViews needed and initialise them with images, then display them on screen at set positions. I would then preload the next levels images using GCD. When a continue button is pressed I will set the UIImages and the UIImageViews to nil and display level 2's (or the next level) on screen.

I'm not confident in my approach and was wondering if there was something that would make it simpler or something I've missed or even if in practice it will work accordingly to the theory.

Thank you in advance for you time and any help.
Sorry if this is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use a single view controller class for all your levels and load the levels from some .plist file or other format.

Don't bother using GCD. Loading 4 images once per level during loading costs practically nothing.

If all you need to do is have 2-4 images on the screen for each level (in addition to any other level elements), simply create 4 `UIImageView` instances and add them to your view. Then when you load a level, create new `UIImage` objects from the required image files and set your `UIImageViews`' image property to them. The `UIImage` objects of the old level will be released and deallocated at that moment, since you (and the `UIImageViews`) don't have a strong reference to them anymore.

Pseudo implementation:

```
- (void)loadLevel:(int)levelNumber {
    // Assuming you have your image views in an array imageViews.
    // Determine the image files required for this level.
    // Put them into an array imageNames.

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (imageNames.count < i) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNames[i]];
            [self.imageViews[i] setImage:image];
        } else {
            [self.imageViews[i] setImage:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: i disagree partly, depending on the size of the images being loaded, they can block the main thread for a noticeable amount of time. Im currently working on an app that loads up images that are roughly 1000x1000 and if its done on the main thread the app pauses for a few milliseconds which is noticeable. loading up 4 smaller ones could result in the same consequences.

Comment: thats if this loading of the images happens while the game is in motion, if its done in a loading screen or something then yes dont bother

Comment: Well, OP didn't specify sizes. I was assuming the images are some hints, gems or some other level elements, not full screen images or textures. And OP also didn't mention any lags or reason for using GCD and just seems to have general problems with `UIImage` and `UIImageViews` judging from the title. So I tried to provide the simplest solution. But of course this won't fit all situations.